# call notifyItemRangeChanged on child adapter of ConcatAdapter doesn't work

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-concatadapter

I have two adapters inside a ConcatAdapter, when I invoke `notifyItemRangeChanged()` on one of the child adapters, the RecyclerView does not response.

For details, before I call `notifyItemRangeChanged()`, I added some data to the child adapter.

Say the child adapter contains 10 items at the beginning, then I appended 10 new items to it, and I want the recyclerView to show the appended items by calling `notifyItemRangeChanged(10, 10)`, with no luck.

However, I found `notifyItemRangeInserted()` works just fine. Any one knowns why?

Comment: `changed` is for notifying about updates/replacement. If you're adding items then `inserted` is the right method to call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are adding new data to your list in that case `notifyItemRangeInserted()` should be called as it's name says. `notifyItemRangeChanged()` is used when you have  updated the existing data range.

Comment: Thank u for your answer. But the strange thing is, when I'm not using ConcatAdapter, `notifyItemRangeChanged()` is able to show the added items, I'm wondering how could it work...